# I can't empty/update my woocommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

A site that I work on has a woocommerce shop in it. For some reason there are 5 items in the cart regardless of where you visit the site from and you cannot update/empty the cart. When you hover over the little basket icon on the shop page, it says there are 0 items but when you click the link it always has these 5 items. It doesn't matter if you try remove or update the number of items - nothing happens.

I've made sure all my custom templates are up to date and have all green ticks on the system status. I've also cleared the transients, expired transients and sessions to no effect whatsoever. I don't have a caching plugin and have activated and deactivated other plugins on the site. I have also tried to visit the link on the buttons via the URL bar in case there was an issue with the AJAX request not working properly.

Also this problem does not exist on a local version of the site.

Comment: Kindly, this kind of issue is related (most of the time) to your theme and the best way to solve it is to contact theme authors support…

Comment: Hi, there is a mode for debugging that can disable the theme. The same thing happens when I use that mode.

Comment: If you switch to a wordpress default theme (making a database backup before), I am sure that you will not get this anymore. This is certainly related to your theme and have to be solved by your theme authors support…

Comment: It might be mistake in header part html integration please check <?php wp_head(); ?> is there or not in header.php

Answer (score 0):

The client had enabled a page editor on the theme which is incompatible with the Woocommerce pages on the site. Thanks for your advice @LoicTheAztec